# Nginx conditional redirect to https

Tags: nginx

I have a situation where although all the traffic should redirect http to https except when the context is /publish

http{mydomain.com/*} should force redirect to  https{mydomain.com} but not in case if the url is http{mydomain.com/publish}, no redirect needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do redirect in nginx is using multiple `server{}` blocks.
You should be fine with something like that:

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.com;
  listen 80;

  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
  location /publish {
    # Here goes your usual request handling, with proxying and so on
    # Nested location can be used if needed
  }
}

server {
  server_name mydomain.com;
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  # Here goes all your request handling 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned code by @Hardy is fine with two servers, the other way could be to put the redirect code in if block at the beginning,

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  if ($request_uri ~ "publish") {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
  ...
  location / {
    ...
  }
  ...
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  ...
}
```

If you need it to be with just single server, you can define both ports in the same server and https required code, and then remove the second server, in the following way,

```
map $request_uri $tmp_do_redirect {
  "~publish" 1;
  default  0;
}
map $scheme $do_redirect {
  "https" 0;
  default  $tmp_do_redirect;
}   
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  #https code, like ssl, certificate, etc#
  ...
  if ($do_redirect = "1") {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
  ...
  location / {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does `map` have any significant performance impact on request handling?

Comment: @PF4Public I'm sorry, I don't have much idea about that, just a noob, may be https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith could help