# Nginx conditionally rewrite uri

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple Rails apps (using Nixy). I need to rewrite some requests to inject a string in front of url, if is missing.

For example:
If I have `http://proxy_ip/app_name/some/root` I don't want to modify anything, but if I have `http://proxy_ip/some/root` I want to transform in `http://proxy_ip/app_name/some/root`

I tried `rewrite ^ /app_name/$uri;` but it doesn't work, and I have no idea how to conditionally do that rewrite.

Comment: Searching for your exact title turns up many hits right here on SO, have you tried any of the approaches described in any of them?  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526436/nginx-conditional-rewrite-issue), [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181475/nginx-conditional-redirect-to-https).

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181475/nginx-conditional-redirect-to-https ?

Comment: You may find an if statement example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181475/nginx-conditional-redirect-to-https

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map to detect the missing app name, then return 301 with the missing app name.

```
map $uri $prepend_app_name {
    ~^/some/root(/.*)?$ app_name;
}

server {
    if ($prepend_app_name) {
        return 301 /$prepend_app_name$uri;
    }
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the comments and in case try with an if statement keeping in mind what nginx documentation advices: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/